# Elements with both relative and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I want to render some elements that are relatively positioned next to each other but are absolutely positioned above everything else. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OZMg.png) for what I would like to render and the fiddle below (or [this codepen](https://codepen.io/jimmycod23/pen/pxzMaa)) for my attempt at trying to get it to work. Thanks!

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.tallBox {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  background: orange;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
}

.bar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 442px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  // position: absolute;
}

.gap {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Proposal: </h2>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OZMg.png">
<div class="gap"></div>

<h2>Current rendering without any changing any position properties:</h2>
<section class="row">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
<section class="row">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</section>

<div class="gap"></div>

<h2>Attempt:</h2>
<section class="row special">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="tallBox"></div>
    <div class="tallBox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
<section class="row">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my question:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.tallBox {
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute
}

.tallBox-container {
  positin: relative;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.bar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 442px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}


.group {
  display: flex;
  // position: absolute;
}

.gap {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="row special">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="tallBox-container">   
      <div class="tallBox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tallBox-container"> 
      <div class="tallBox"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
<section class="row">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably consider negative margin and avoid the use of `position:absolute`

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.tallBox {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  background: orange;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-bottom:-50px;
}

.bar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 442px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  z-index:2;
}

.gap {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="row special">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="tallBox"></div>
    <div class="tallBox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
<section class="row">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</section>
```